# Is this the correct way to mock HttpContextBase, HttpRequestBase and HttpResponseBase for Unit Testing Cookies?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Given the following class to write and read cookies:

```
public static class CookieManager
{
    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///     Writes a new cookie on the.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="response">The <see cref="HttpResponseBase"/> that is used to write the cookies.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the cookie.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the cookie.</param>
    public static void Write(HttpResponseBase response, string name, string value)
    {
        var applicationCookie = new HttpCookie(name) { Value = value, Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) };
        response.Cookies.Add(applicationCookie);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Reads a cookie.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The <see cref="HttpRequestBase"/> that is used to read cookies.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the cookie to read.</param>
    /// <param name="defaultValue">The value to return when the cookie does not exists.</param>
    /// <returns>The value of the cookie if it's exists, otherwise the defautValue.</returns>
    public static string Read(HttpRequestBase request, string name, string defaultValue)
    {
        if (request.Cookies[name] != null)
        {
            return request.Cookies[name].Value;
        }

        return defaultValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Check if a cookie does exists.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The <see cref="HttpRequestBase"/> that is used to read cookies.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the cookie.</param>
    /// <returns><see langword="true" /> when the cookie does exists, otherwise <see langword="false" />.</returns>
    public static bool Exists(HttpRequestBase request, string name)
    {
        if (request.Cookies[name] != null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now, I do have a unit test and I want to test my CookieManager.
Here's the unit test:

```
/// <summary>
///     Checks if the repository of the logs does contain an entry.
/// </summary>
[TestMethod]
public void then_the_cookie_should_be_present_in_the_cookiecollection()
{
    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();

    response.SetupGet(x => x.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
    request.SetupGet(x => x.Cookies).Returns(response.Object.Cookies);
    context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
    context.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);

    CookieManager.Write(response.Object, "CookieName", "CookieValue");
    var cookie = CookieManager.Read(request.Object, "CookieName", "Default");

    Assert.AreEqual("CookieValue", cookie, "The value retrieved from the cookie is incorrect.");
}
```

I know that this test is working, but I want to make sure that it's the correct way of testing or if there is any better solution.

I know CodeReview, but I do think the question is best placed here. If not, my aplogies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing against HttpContextBase is hard as it is closely coupled to the web framework. So the HttpContextBase class can be thought as [Humble Object Pattern](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html). This means that you don't necessarily need to test the logic in HttpContextBase.

To make HttpContextBase humble, you need to extract abstraction from logic of HttpContextBase as the following.

```
public interface ICookies
{
    string this[string name]{ get; set; }
}
```

And then, you can create the humble class, which isn't under test.

```
public class Cookies : ICookies
{
    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[name];
            if (cookie == null)
                throw new KeyNotFoundException();
            return cookie.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[name];
            if (cookie == null)
                throw new KeyNotFoundException();
            cookie.Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Your target class will be changed as below.

```
public static class CookieManager
{
    public static void Write(ICookies cookies, string name, string value)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

This would not be the best, but if I fall into your case, I will do like this.